# Comparison operators in C++

Tags: c++

I've got two questions regarding comparison operators in C++:

1. When looping, which of two ways is more efficient (type of `mdata` and `mfirst_free` is `double*`, too):

`for (double *p = mdata; p < mfirst_free; ++p) { .. }`

`for (double *p = mdata; p != mfirst_free; ++p) { .. }`

I'll guess in the advance the same answer is valid for all primitive types - `int`, `double`, and pointers. Right?
I know  `<` version is safer because if I somehow start with bigger pointer than expected it won't be infinite loop. But, when I'm sure I won't get invalid input, which version is more efficient?

2. When overriding comparison operators in my own classes, are there some combinations that are the most efficient, and is there minimal required (or recommended) combination for deducing the rest?

Let's take hypothetical situation of trying to save every processor cycle - what are the best choices? Are there some that are others more elegant?

Comment: I'm comparing pointers on doubles, not doubles themselves. It's looping over the array of doubles, without keeping bounds as integers, but as pointers, too.

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot it. But still, I don't think asking what's more efficient is useless. You should inspect the generated assembly code for each of your variants.

Comment: Regarding the second question, (1) I think you mean "efficient", not "effective", and (2) it depends very much on whether you're using library facilities such as the C++ standard library that for obscure reasons are based on using `operator<` instead of `compare`.

Comment: `s/I don't think/I think/` please.

Comment: What can libraries in C++ deduce from another, and what can not? It would be logical that `compare` is deduced from `operator`-overrides, but it seems it doesn't? Can (all) operators deduced one from another?

Comment: @tbukic: `compare` is the most fundamental & efficient for the in-practice, because for the in-practice integer overflow can usually be disregarded and so most often it's just a subtraction. However, the standard library only adds support for deducing other operators from `operator<`, namely the operators defined in namespace `std::relop`.(IIRC). Deducing `operator==` and `operator!=` from `operator<` involves two comparisons and thus is inefficient. I find it very convenient to have a CRTP-based class to provide all the relational operations in terms of `compare`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always, see for yourself and look at the generated code. With g++ 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04, you get

```
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addq    $8, -32(%rbp)
.L2:
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    cmpq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    jb  .L3
```

---

```
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    addq    $8, -24(%rbp)
.L4:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    cmpq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    jne .L5
```

As you can see, the only relevant difference is `jb .L3` vs `jne .L5`.

So, I would say both are equivalent from a performance point of view.

---

Answering the second question, the minimum necessary for comparison is `operator<`. You can deduce everything else from this, e.g.

```
bool operator==(const T &x, const T &y) {
    return !(x < y) && !(y < x);
}

bool operator!=(const T &x, const T &y) {
    return !(x == y);
}

bool operator>(const T &x, const T &y) {
    return y < x;
}

bool operator<=(const T &x, const T &y) {
    return !(y < x);
}

bool operator>=(const T &x, const T &y) {
    return !(x < y);
}
```

Of course, this is only true if you have the usual comparison semantics.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in pure c++ terms there is no correct answer to your question since the standard does not specify it and it's left to the compiler and CPU's discretion.

In real terms you're asking whether a 'branch if not equal' instruction takes any less time than a 'branch if less' instruction. In all CPUs I have ever encountered the answer will be 'no' - provided you don't get wrong-footed by incorrect branch prediction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it really doesn't make a difference. I believe that

```
p != mfirst_free
```

would be translated to something in assembly similar to

```
   loop        
               CMP   p mfirst_free
               BEQ   exit
              {...body...}
               B     loop
   exit
```

while the

```
p < mfirst_free
```

would translate to the same, but instead of a BEQ instruction it would be a BGE. Same number of instructions take would take the same amount of time to be executed.

-There are various ways to translate a for loop to assembly, but my point here is that every comparison operator that you use would lead to the same running time, as far as I know.-

Comment: Re "it really make a difference", did you intend to have "does not" in there?

Comment: Omg, my bad. Yeah, it should be a "does not".

Answer (score 1):

If the counter variable is an integer or pointer, there is probably no difference in efficiency. The effect is the same as long as the variable is just being incremented (by one) and start out smaller or equal and the end value.

But C++ iterators don't necessarily implement `operator<`. In fact only `RandomAccessIterator` are required to do so (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). So C++11 translates `for(auto&& v : values)` to `for(auto it = std::begin(values); it != std::end(values); ++it)`. For example `std::forward_list` only has `ForwardIterators` and so `operator<` can't be used to iterate through it.

If you use OpenMP for parallelization `operator<` is needed:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(auto it = std::begin(values); it < std::end(values); ++it)
```

Because it needs to split the loop into smaller loops.

I guess in general it would be best to use `operator!=` to be compatible with all iterator types, unless you do something else than iterate (increment by more than one, etc.), use floating point values as counter, or use OpenMP.

Comment: I accepted this because of great tip on usage, but Olaf edited answer and only answered my question completely. Thanx a lot for the tip, anyway!